# Is it possible to call two javascript functions on one html event?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying something like this:

```
<textarea onFocus = "myFunction(1)" onBlur = "myFunction(0); return submitform();">
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The function you run can call multiple functions as the [syntax you have there does](http://jsbin.com/misupoge/1/edit?html,output). What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but the syntax is wrong, see this edited textarea:

```
 <textarea onfocus="myFunction(1);" onblur="myFunction(0); return submitform();">
             ^------                  ^-------- small letter is important
```

A yet better way would be to attach jQuery event handlers, or similiar with a different preferred framework.

Comment: note : attaching events to elements is also possible in pure JS without frameworks

Comment: HTML attribute names are case insensitive.

Comment: @Quentin in XHTML, `onFocus` is invalid: `You have used the attribute named above in your document, but the document type you are using does not support that attribute for this element.`

Comment: @DanFromGermany — So what? The question is tagged `html` not `xhtml`.

Comment: @Quentin xhtml is html too, don't be a nitpicker. It's better to get used to good coding standards than to enforce the bad ones.

Comment: XHTML isn't HTML, it is a close cousin of it that most people don't use… and most of the people who do use it serve it as `text/html` so browsers parse it using HTML rules instead of XHTML rules. Unless someone is explicitly using XHTML, telling them that their attribute names must be lower case is simply wrong.

Comment: @DanFromGermany — Please refer to the MIME type registry and stop reading so much into the name of the specification.

Comment: … and even if you do choose class XHTML as HTML, it could only be classed as a *subset* so any advice given that is XHTML specific should still be XHTML specific since it doesn't apply to the rest of HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The text between the two "" is actually considered as a function. So it is a unnamed function calls your other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by @DanFromGermny is right,

you can try this also

```
<textarea onfocus="myFunction(1);" onblur="(function(){myFunction(0); return submitform();})(event)">
```